# prevent nested groups from spoiling regexp matches (TCL)

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a file with a number of (multi)space separated floats. Number of floats could vary. For the sake of the argument let's say it's 5. I picked up a regexp from this tutorial page :

[www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

To catch multiple floats I stuck this into a group added some spaces and grouped it again with ? quantifier.

```
(([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)\s+)+
```

I understand that has created nested groups and that's where my knowledge ends. When I test the regexp I get undesired matches of 'sub' groups i.e. the exponents.

So my question is: how do I capture only the 'first level' groups that are my full floats?

A sample test data set (note varying number of spaces):

```
set x "  1.0034e-09 -0.34e+07    -3 0.46   3.445e+03   "
```

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your expression contains nested capturing groups does not mean you will be able to access those repeated captures, the only one accessible will be the text captured during the last iteration.

Also, each capturing group is returned in Tcl, and if you do not need it, convert all capturing groups into non-capturing (`([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)` => `(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`).

To match all the numbers in your testing set, you may use

```
set x {  1.0034e-09 -0.34e+07    -3 0.46   3.445e+03   }
set RE {[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?}
set res [regexp -all -inline $RE $x]
puts $res
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/VNob8V)

**NOTE** that the `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` regex matches *integer* OR *float* values. To only match *floats*, use `[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` (remove the optional - *one or zero occurrences* - `?` quantifier after `\.`).